# Create sorted List ordered by order in another List

Tags: c#

I have a List of items already ordered by priority, and a set of unsorted items. Each unsorted item may or may not appear in the prioritised list.

How do I create a new List that contains only the unsorted items that appear in the priority List, in the order they appear in the priority List?

e.g.

```
List<Foo> priorityList = GetPriorityList();
IEnumerable<Foo> unsorteditems = GetSomeItems();

List<Foo> prioritisedItems = new List<Foo>();

foreach (var item in unsorteditems)
{
  if (priorityList.Contains(item))
  {
    //Add item to prioritisedItems in the order it appears in priorityList
  }
}
```

A crude implementation is easy, but seems messy and inefficient:

```
List<Foo> sortedList = new List<Foo>();

  foreach (var item in unsortedItems)
  {
    if (priorityList.Contains(item) && !sortedList.Contains(item))
    {
      if (sortedList.Count() < 1)
      {
        sortedList.Add(item);
      }
      else
      {
        foreach (var sortedItem in sortedList)
        {
          if (priorityList.IndexOf(sortedItem) < priorityList.IndexOf(item))
          {
            sortedList.Insert(sortedList.IndexOf(sortedItem), item);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Other questions about this topic seem to a) use a property of the items to order by, or b) assume that all unsorted items will appear in the already-sorted list.

EDIT:

As requested, here's the Foo object in this specific case:

```
public partial class Erpstatuscodes
  {
    public string ProgramCode { get; set; }
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string StatusCodeDescription { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string TestInstructions { get; set; }
    public string SampleType { get; set; }
    public string StatusType { get; set; }
  }
```

The unsortedItems will be pulled from EntityFramework, but the priorityList items will be deserialised from a config file.

Also, to clarify, this is using .NET Framework 4.8, not .NET Core.

Comment: Does `Foo` implement `IEquatable<Foo>` and override `GetHashCode`? If not, can you? Or does `Foo` have a scalar identiifer, like `Int32 FooId { get; }`?

Comment: @Dai No, the only basis for comparison is the order of items in the priorityList.

Comment: So you're relying on object-reference-equality to see if `Foo` values are equal? Is that reliable?

Comment: @Dai Sorry, I misinterpreted your comment. Yes, Foo could be made to implement IEquatable<Foo>, to allow comparing Foo using Foo.Equals(Foo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that `Foo` does not have any members to compare it with, so I assume then that `Foo` is a `class` (not a `struct`) and that you're relying on object-reference-equality (`==` or `Object.ReferenceEquals`)), which is what your `priorityList.IndexOf(sortedItem)` code did under-the-hood, in which this code below should work:

```
Dictionary<Foo,Int32> priorityListIndexes = priorityList
    .Select( ( foo, idx ) => ( foo, idx ) )
    .ToDictionary( t => t.foo, t => t.idx);

List<Foo> prioritisedItems = unsorteditems
    .Select( unsortedFoo => ( foo: unsortedFoo, ok: priorityListIndexes.TryGetValue( unsortedFoo, out Int32 idx ), idx: idx ) )
    .Where( t => t.ok )
    .OrderBy( t => t.idx )
    .Select( t => t.foo )
    .ToList();
```

Note that *generally speaking* it's a bad idea to use reference-types for `TKey`, but in cases like these it's okay.

---

This can actually be simplified to a single `.Join` (with the same caveat that `Foo` reference-equality is acceptable for the join predicate):

```
List<Foo> prioritisedItems = Enumerable
    .Join<Foo>(
        outer           : priorityList.Select( ( foo, idx ) => ( foo, idx ) ),
        inner           : unsorteditems,
        outerKeySelector: t => t.foo,
        innerKeySelector: foo => foo,
        resultSelector  : ( left, right ) => ( left.idx, right )
    )
    .OrderBy( t => t.idx )
    .Select( t => t.foo )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What if I implement IEquatable<Foo>? Does that provide a simpler solution?

Comment: @aforest-ccc Implementing `IEquatable<Foo>` wouldn't alter the code in my answer at all, and you only need to implement `IEquatable<Foo>` **if reference-equality is insufficient for your application** (and if you do, you **must** override `GetHashCode` too). I cannot answer that question because I don't know what `Foo` is or if you can depend on reference-equality or not.

Comment: Relying on reference-equality doesn't seem sound, so implementing IEquatable<Foo> seems wise. But overriding GetHashCode seems like it would add a lot of otherwise-unnecessary complexity to a simple Foo class, so is it worth it to implement IEquatable?

Comment: @aforest-ccc I think you should post the definition of `Foo` to your question and explain how `Foo` instances are created (are you using Entity Framework / an ORM / deserialization?). Additionally, implementing `GetHashCode` is straightforward in .NET Core now.

Comment: Done. Sadly this is using .NET Framework because it's a legacy project, so no .NET Core niceties for me.